# How to only change the colour of the item symbol of an alerted item?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have an incrementally uncovered itemized list (code below).

How can I prevent the text of the 3rd item from being dyed in the alert colour? I would like to just have the item symbol's colour changed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Items}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item<+-| alert@+-> CCCCC
    \item D
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It may not be optimal, but `\item<+-| alert@+-> \textcolor{black}{CCCCC}` would do.

Comment: Does the solution have to be automatic? Otherwise `\color{black}CCCCC` might be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, @Steven and @samcarter, `\color{black}` is what I am currently using as a workaround. Of course, an automatic solution would be desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own action environment or redefine the alert action.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% defining new action environment
\newenvironment{checkenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=green}}}{}
% redefining alert action
\renewenvironment{alertenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Items}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A
    \item<+-| check@+-> B
    \item<+-| alert@+-> CCCCC
    \item D
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit: as suggested by samcarter**

Simply redefining the alert action as shown above will basically disable the `\alert` command. With the `etoolbox` package `\AtBeginEnvironment` can be used to only change it for the `itemize` environment. But of course, `\alert` won't work inside the environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% not necessary with up-to-date beamer versions
% defining new action environment
\newenvironment{checkenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=green}}}{}
% redefining alert action only for itemize
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
\renewenvironment{alertenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}}}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Items}
  Alert working outside itemize, \alert{before}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A alert \alert{not working} inside itemize
    \item<+-| check@+-> B
    \item<+-| alert@+-> CCCCC
    \item D
  \end{itemize}
  and \alert{after} it.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great Idea! May I suggest `\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\renewenvironment{alertenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}}}{}}`? This will leave the `\alert` command usable for the rest of the document.

Comment: @samcarter added this to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the edit. Just updated beamer.