# Beamer highlight current item in list both in bold and with another item symbol

Tags: beamer, fonts, environments, itemize, overlays

1. Suppose that I have an `itemize` list, which I want to present in sequential order. I use `[<+->]` for that.
2. I want to highlight the current (the most recently added) item in bold.
   To do so, I replace `[<+->]` with `[<+-|alert@+>]` and change `alert` color and font following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458586/283836):

```
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black} %change the font color
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %make alerted text bold
```

Result with current item in bold:
[image: bold]

3. Moreover, I want to change the item shape from a circle to a triangle only for the most recently added item to the list. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389088/283836), I modify `alert` behaviour in itemize:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
\renewenvironment{alertenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}}
```

However, since I've redefined `alert` environment, the bold for current item is no longer working:
[image: item]

4. This is the result I want to achieve (combination of two modifications at the same time):
   [image: ideal]

### MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

% redefining alert action only for itemize
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
\renewenvironment{alertenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}}


\begin{frame}{Future work}
\begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black} %change the font color
    \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %make alerted text bold
    \item Fix the global warming
    \item Prove P $\ne$ NP
    \item Sofa in the office 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\alt` macro to provide an alternative symbol:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\alt<.>{\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}{\textbullet}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Future work}
\begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black} %change the font color
    \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %make alerted text bold
    \item Fix the global warming
    \item Prove P $\ne$ NP
    \item Sofa in the office 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: First time I see `alt` in action, the same is true for setting `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}` INSIDE the `itemize` environment.

Comment: I have to check the manual if that is something that I can learn on my own.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The `\alt` macro is described in section "9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications" of the user guide. If that's the first time you see `\alt`, just wait until you see `\temporal` - that's even rarer :)

Comment: Haha, thanks for the follow-up!